# How to achieve semi-transparent EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, material-design, android-cardview

I would like to recreate this layout but I'm unable to do this.
I need instructions/guidelines for making the semi-transparent TextInputEditText and the 2-corned-curved card view.

Thanks!

Source: material.io[image]

Comment: what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Set below code to the android:background="@drawable/abc" of Editext

abc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid
      android:color="#8c000000"/>

<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="17dp"
    android:topRightRadius="17dp"/>

</shape>
```

**Hex opacity values**

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Answer (score 0):

For rounded corners create xml in drawable

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#CCCCCC"/>
</shape>
```

Try this for semi transparent background in editText

```
   android:alpha=".6"
```

Answer (score 0):

**For EditText**

Create **edit_text_bg.xml** file in the drawable folder and add below code into it.

android:background="drawable/edit_text_bg" to your EditText

```html
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent">
    </solid>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</shape>
```

**For Corned-Curved Shape.**

Create **curved_bg.xml** file in the drawable folder and add below code into it.

```html
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white">
    </solid>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```